# Deploying Spring Cloud Eureka in AWS ECS (EC2) with DNS props but getting: 'Failed to bind elastic IP (IP)'. I attached a policy to allow user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using AWS ECS to deploy Eureka in my Cluster to zones inside us-east-1 region. ECS dynamically deploys to any region and I cannot predetermine the IP or domain the EC2 instance will be, hence I use DNS.

I am using DNS as illustrated here https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Deploying-Eureka-Servers-in-EC2. Below are my configurations:

```
eureka:
    instance:
        healthCheckUrlPath: /manage/health
    client:
        region: us-east-1
        availabilityZones:
            us-east-1: us-east-1a,us-east-1c
        eurekaServerPort: 8761
        useDnsForFetchingServiceUrls: true
        eurekaServerDNSName: eureka.mydomain.com
        eurekaServerURLContext: eureka
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true

cloud:
    aws:
        credentials:
            accessKey: AWS_KEY
            secretKey: AWS_KEY_SECRET
        region:
            static: us-east-1
```

The user with AWS_KEY has this policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AllocateAddress",
                "ec2:AssociateAddress",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DisassociateAddress"
            ],
            "Sid": "Stmt1375723773000",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

and configured the EurekaInstanceConfigBean configured as:

```
@Bean
    @Profile("!default")
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils) {
        EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
        AmazonInfo info = AmazonInfo.Builder.newBuilder().autoBuild("eureka");
        info.getMetadata().put(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.publicHostname.getName(), info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.publicIpv4));
        config.setHostname(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.publicHostname));
        config.setIpAddress(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.publicIpv4));
        config.setNonSecurePort(port);
        config.setDataCenterInfo(info);
        return config;
    }
```

**GOOD THING:** Eureka recognise my Route 53 configured `eureka.mydomain.com`  DNS EIPs and it tries to bind, the (available and unassigned) EIP in zone us-east-1c, to the instance where my eureka server is deployed

**PROBLEM**: I get the following logs and Unauthorized error as below when booting my app:

```
...................................
.................................
2017-04-10 16:07:42.141 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.a.DnsTxtRecordClusterResolver  : Resolved txt.us-east-1.eureka.mydomain.com to [AwsEndpoint{ serviceUrl=
'http://ec2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8761/eureka', region='us-east-1', zone='us-east-1c'}]
2017-04-10 16:07:42.141 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.a.ZoneAffinityClusterResolver  : Local zone=us-east-1c; resolved to: [AwsEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://ec2-3
4.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8761/eureka', region='us-east-1', zone='us-east-1c'}]
2017-04-10 16:07:42.204  INFO 5 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2017-04-10 16:07:42.209  INFO 5 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2017-04-10 16:07:42.209  INFO 5 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2017-04-10 16:07:42.209  INFO 5 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2017-04-10 16:07:42.209  INFO 5 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2017-04-10 16:07:42.209  INFO 5 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2017-04-10 16:07:42.211  INFO 5 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2017-04-10 16:07:42.213 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.SessionedEurekaHttpClient    : Ending a session and starting anew
2017-04-10 16:07:42.222 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] n.d.s.t.j.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient : Created client for url: http://ec2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com:87
61/eureka
2017-04-10 16:07:42.313 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.shared.MonitoredConnectionManager  : Get connection: {}->http://ec2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8761,
timeout = 5000
2017-04-10 16:07:42.314 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : [{}->http://ec2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8761] total kept aliv
e: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 200
2017-04-10 16:07:42.314 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : No free connections [{}->http://ec2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8
761][null]
2017-04-10 16:07:42.314 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : Available capacity: 50 out of 50 [{}->http://ec2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.am
azonaws.com:8761][null]
2017-04-10 16:07:42.314 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : Creating new connection [{}->http://ec2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.c
om:8761]
2017-04-10 16:07:42.330 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.shared.MonitoredConnectionManager  : Released connection is not reusable.
2017-04-10 16:07:42.331 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : Releasing connection [{}->http://ec2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com:
8761][null]
2017-04-10 16:07:42.331 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.shared.NamedConnectionPool         : Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2017-04-10 16:07:42.331 DEBUG 5 --- [           main] n.d.s.t.j.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient : Jersey HTTP GET http://ec2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8761/eurek
a/apps/?; statusCode=N/A
2017-04-10 16:07:42.345 ERROR 5 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution 
....................
....................
2017-04-10 16:07:49.455 DEBUG 5 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.discovery.endpoint.EndpointUtils     : This client will talk to the following serviceUrls in order : [http://ec2-
34.206.31.211.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8761/eureka/]
2017-04-10 16:07:49.455 DEBUG 5 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.discovery.endpoint.EndpointUtils     : The region url to be looked up is txt.us-east-1.eureka.mydomain.com :
2017-04-10 16:07:49.456 DEBUG 5 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.discovery.endpoint.EndpointUtils     : The zoneName mapped to region us-east-1 is us-east-1c
2017-04-10 16:07:49.456 DEBUG 5 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.discovery.endpoint.EndpointUtils     : Checking if the instance zone us-east-1c is the same as the zone from DNS
us-east-1c
2017-04-10 16:07:49.456 DEBUG 5 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.discovery.endpoint.EndpointUtils     : The zone index from the list [us-east-1c] that matches the instance zone u
s-east-1c is 0
2017-04-10 16:07:49.456 DEBUG 5 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.discovery.endpoint.EndpointUtils     : The zone url to be looked up is txt.us-east-1c.eureka.mydomain.com :
2017-04-10 16:07:49.457 DEBUG 5 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.discovery.endpoint.EndpointUtils     : The eureka url for the dns name txt.us-east-1c.eureka.mydomain.com is e
c2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com
2017-04-10 16:07:49.457 DEBUG 5 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.discovery.endpoint.EndpointUtils     : The EC2 url is http://ec2-34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8761/eureka
/
2017-04-10 16:07:49.457 DEBUG 5 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.discovery.endpoint.EndpointUtils     : This client will talk to the following serviceUrls in order : [http://ec2-
34.200.47.82.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8761/eureka/]
**2017-04-10 16:07:49.527 ERROR 5 --- [      Thread-11] com.netflix.eureka.aws.EIPManager        : Failed to bind elastic IP: 34.200.47.82 to i-0bc1018ccdcc69148

com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: You are not authorized to perform this operation. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 403; Error Code: UnauthorizedOperation; Request I
D: f9b2dec4-6d79-4da2-bbac-061416bde000)**
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1378) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:924) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:702) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:454) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:416) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:365) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.doInvoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:12003) ~[aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:11973) ~[aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeAddresses(AmazonEC2Client.java:4716) ~[aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.11.18.jar!/:na]
        at com.netflix.eureka.aws.EIPManager.bindEIP(EIPManager.java:202) [eureka-core-1.4.12.jar!/:1.4.12]
        at com.netflix.eureka.aws.EIPManager.handleEIPBinding(EIPManager.java:136) [eureka-core-1.4.12.jar!/:1.4.12]
        at com.netflix.eureka.aws.EIPManager.start(EIPManager.java:105) [eureka-core-1.4.12.jar!/:1.4.12]
        at com.netflix.eureka.aws.AwsBinderDelegate.start(AwsBinderDelegate.java:42) [eureka-core-1.4.12.jar!/:1.4.12]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerBootstrap.initEurekaServerContext(EurekaServerBootstrap.java:145) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-serve
r-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerBootstrap.contextInitialized(EurekaServerBootstrap.java:81) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-1.2.
6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration$1.run(EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration.java:70) [spring-cloud-netflix-e
ureka-server-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

2017-04-10 16:07:49.527  INFO 5 --- [      Thread-11] com.netflix.eureka.aws.EIPManager        : No EIP is free to be associated with this instance. Candidate EIPs are: [3
4.200.47.82]
......................................
........................................
........................................
```

**QUESTION**: I have attached the policy to allow Eureka to bind the Elastic IP to the instance where it is deployed but WHY am I getting a `You are not authorized to perform this operation. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 403; Error Code: UnauthorizedOperation`  and how can I fix this? As it stands, I have spend more than a day Googling and still the same error :(

I tried the netflix way of configuring eureka like below but to no avail :(:

```
eureka:
        awsAccessId: AWS_KEY
        awsSecretKey:AWS_KEY_SECRET
        asgName: EIPAccessPolicyGroup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got a solution and had help from [@DirkLachowski](https://github.com/DirkLachowski) and [@spencergibb](https://github.com/spencergibb) on [this post](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/188). Thanks a lot guys. So I only had to change this:

```
eureka:
        awsAccessId: AWS_KEY
        awsSecretKey:AWS_KEY_SECRET
        asgName: EIPAccessPolicyGroup
```

To this:

```
eureka:
    server:
        aWSAccessId: AWS_KEY
        aWSSecretKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY
        asgName: EC2ContainerService_AUTO_SCALING_GROUP_CREATED_BY_ECS_FOR_MY_CLUSTER
```

So each eureka server bind an unused/free EIP that I put on my TXT DNS records to the EC2 instance where my eureka server is running :)